# Make Sitecore contact as inactive when exm bounce contact email

Tags: exm, contact-facets, contact

I have one EXM which I am sending to multiple contacts available in xDB. When email bounce for contact (reach to Undelivered Max count)  I want to mark that contact as inactive using custom facets but I am really not sure where Sitecore stores "Bounce count" for a specific contact. Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sitecore stores information about email addresses in `EmailAddressList` facet (`Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.EmailAddressList`).

`EmailAddressList` contains:

```
public EmailAddress PreferredEmail { get; set; }

public Dictionary<string, EmailAddress> Others { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, EmailAddress>();
```

That allows contact to have preferred email and a list of other email addresses as well. Both `PreferredEmail` and `Others` use `EmailAddress` class that has:

```
public string SmtpAddress { get; set; }

public int BounceCount { get; set; }
```

And here is your `BounceCount` - it's stored separately for each email address.

Comment: Thanks Marek. I found it in EmailAddressList